# Using ActionMailer in a Rails Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, actionmailer

I'm trying to create my first Rails plugin and am having some troubles leveraging ActionMailer in it. The plugin just collects user feedback and emails it off a given address so in terms of functionality it's not too complicated...

All the functionality was working perfectly in my original application until I decided to pluginise this stuff. I've been following the railsguide on creating a plugin as much as possible and you can find my entire plugin's source here:

http://github.com/gshankar/rocket_feedback

Though I'm pretty sure the problem is in one of these files:

1- The file that loads everything in: rocket_feedback/lib/rocket_feedback.rb

```
require 'rocket_feedback/routing'
require 'action_mailer'

%w{ models controllers }.each do |dir|
  path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app', dir)
  $LOAD_PATH << path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_paths << path
  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.load_once_paths.delete(path)
end
```

2- The controller which calls the deliver_feedback method rocket_feedback/lib/app/controllers/rocket_feedback_controller.rb

```
class RocketFeedbackController < ApplicationController

  #Email method for feedback
  def send_feedback
      subject = params["subject"]
      from = params["email"]
      feedback = params["feedback"]
      RocketFeedback::deliver_feedback(from, subject, feedback)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :text => ''}
      end
   end
end
```

3- The model (which inherits from ActionMailer)

```
class RocketFeedback < ActionMailer::Base

  default_url_options[:host] = HOST

  def feedback(from, subject, feedback)
    @subject = "Feedback: #{subject}"
    @subject_for_message = subject
    @recipients = 'yourname@yourdomain.com' 
    @from = from
    @sent_on = Time.now
    @sent_at = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %I:%M:%S %p").to_s
    @body["sent_at"] = @sent_at
    @body["from"] = from
    @body["feedback"] = feedback
    @body["subject"] = @subject_for_message
    @headers = {}
  end

end
```

The only clue I have is this error message when I try and send feedback via the plugin:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `deliver_feedback' for RocketFeedback:Module):
```

Thanks in advance for you help! (And please feel free to critque my plugin's structure, it's my first attempt so I'm sure I've done all kinds of things wrong...)

Comment: what's your rails version? i'm not sure why but sometimes changing Actionmailer::Base to ActionMailer::ARMailer works

Comment: I'm on 2.3.8, i'll check it out thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `RocketFeedback` class and `RocketFeedback` module in your plugin. The `ActionMailer#deliver_foo` dynamic method is defined through your class. You should call class methods using the `dot` operator.

```
# Instead of this
RocketFeedback::deliver_feedback(from, subject, feedback)
# This should work
RocketFeedback.deliver_feedback(from, subject, feedback)
```

Comment: Thanks Swanand, using your advice (and renaming a few things as well, I had way too many things called RocketFeedback all over my plugin) I was able to get everything working. Cheers!